# Convert Hash Map to 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

What is the easiest way to convert a HashMap  into a 2D array?

Comment: For Java 8+ do it with streams: [relative stack topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51239708/map-to-2d-array-with-streams)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
HashMap map = new HashMap();
Object[][] arr = new Object[map.size()][2];
Set entries = map.entrySet();
Iterator entriesIterator = entries.iterator();

int i = 0;
while(entriesIterator.hasNext()){

    Map.Entry mapping = (Map.Entry) entriesIterator.next();

    arr[i][0] = mapping.getKey();
    arr[i][1] = mapping.getValue();

    i++;
}
```

Comment: Can we create a oneliner now we have streams?

Comment: See one-liner with Java 8 streams [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66106143/389489)

Answer (score 9):

This can only be done when the types of both key and value are the same.

Given:

```
HashMap<String,String> map;
```

I can create an array from this map with this simple loop:

```
String[][] array = new String[map.size()][2];
int count = 0;
for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : map.entrySet()){
    array[count][0] = entry.getKey();
    array[count][1] = entry.getValue();
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

How about

```
Object[][] array = new Object[][]{map.keySet.toArray(), map.entrySet.toArray()};
```

Or, to be more specific about the types, let's say they're `Strings`: `Set`'s `toArray` takes a hint argument, so that

```
String[][] array = new String[][]{map.keySet.toArray(new String[0]), map.entrySet.toArray(new String[0])};
```

**Edit:** I just realized a couple of days later that while this *may* work by chance, in general it shouldn't. The reason is the intermediate `Set`; although it is "backed by the map", there seems to be no explicit guarantee that it will iterate in any particular order. Thus the key- and entry-arrays might not be in the same order, which is a disaster for sure!

Comment: I do like your approach as you're able to do it in one-liners. Yet, why are you using `map.keySet` and `map.entrySet` instead of `map.keySet()` and `map.entrySet()`

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 stream:

```
@Test
void testMapToArray() {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("key1", "value1");
    map.put("key2", 2);

    Object[][] arr =
        map.entrySet().stream()
                .map(e -> new Object[]{e.getKey(), e.getValue()})
                .toArray(Object[][]::new);

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
}
```

Output:

```
[[key1, value1], [key2, 2]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Iterate over your Map using [entrySet](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet()), and fill your array record with the Entry object