# Converting HashMap into Array

Tags: java, android

I have a HashMap which I want to convert into a array.
Which the code below, I get following:
[[2, 11, 10, 9], [value1, value2, value3, value4], [null, null, null, null], [null, null, null, null]]
The "null" entries give me a null pointer exception. Why is it two times as big as it should be? I just want the real entries:
[[2, 11, 10, 9], [value1, value2, value3, value4]]. What did I wrong?

```
String[][] test = getArrayFromHash(hashmap);

    public static String[][] getArrayFromHash(HashMap<String, String> hashMap){
        String[][] str = null;
        {
            Object[] keys = hashMap.keySet().toArray();
            Object[] values = hashMap.values().toArray();
            str = new String[keys.length][values.length];
            for(int i=0;i<keys.length;i++) {
                str[0][i] = (String)keys[i];
                str[1][i] = (String)values[i];
            }
        }
        return str;
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265266/convert-hash-map-to-2d-array):::

```
    String[][] arr = new String[hashmap.size()][2];
    Set entries = hashmap.entrySet();
    Iterator entriesIterator = entries.iterator();

    int i = 0;
    while(entriesIterator.hasNext()){

        Map.Entry mapping = (Map.Entry) entriesIterator.next();

        arr[i][0] = mapping.getKey().toString();
        arr[i][1] = mapping.getValue().toString();

        i++;
    }
```

**UPdated::::** to get two 1D arrays

```
String[] arr1 = new String[hashmap.size()];
String[] arr2 = new String[hashmap.size()];
        Set entries = hashmap.entrySet();
        Iterator entriesIterator = entries.iterator();

        int i = 0;
        while(entriesIterator.hasNext()){

            Map.Entry mapping = (Map.Entry) entriesIterator.next();

            arr1[i] = mapping.getKey().toString();
            arr2[i] = mapping.getValue().toString();

            i++;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! How can I make Strings from these Objekts? I want to put all values into a Spinner, therefore I need Strings.

Comment: I get this exception:05-26 14:02:27.473: W/System.err(22784): java.lang.ClassCastException: [[Ljava.lang.Object;

Comment: can you post your complete logcat?

Comment: mapping.getKey().toString(); replace with mapping.getKey(); and try

Comment: The Error was on the conversion from the 2D-array to a 1D array. This was the code:             for(int i = 0, k = 0; i < test.length; i++)
                for(int j = 0; j < test[0].length; j++, k++)
                 colors[k] = test[i][j];

Comment: you need 2D array or two 1D arrays?

Comment: I need two 1D- arrays, but the first try was one 1D-array

Answer (score 3):

Allocate array of proper size like

```
str = new String[2][values.length];
```

Moreover you should assert that values and keys have the same length. And also that matching entries appear at the same position. Something like

```
String[] keys = hashMap.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
String[] values = new String[keys.length];
String[][] str = {keys, values};
for(int i=0;i<keys.length;i++) values[i] = hashMap.get(keys[i]);
return str;
```

should do (not tested).

Comment: Short, concise, and it looks like it will work to me. And just in case you didn't see my prev comment, I deleted my answer. I realized that Sets don't maintain order, and wasn't sure if I could cast to LinkedHashSet and maintain order before the cast. I see you address that here by using the keys in the keys array to get the actual values from the map itself. Very clever. +1

Comment: Thx. Using an `EntrySet` may be faster. It has the overhead of creating `Map.Entry`, but eliminates the lookups.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if keyset and values will necessary return the values in the same order (it's not specified in the implementation doc so I'd say it's not guaranteed).

try working with entrysets:

```
Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> set = hm.entrySet();
int i = 0;
for (Map.Entry<String,String> me : set) {
  arr[i][0] = me.getKey();
  arr[i][1] = me.getValue()};
  i++;
}
```