# converting Map to 2 dimension array

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a map and trying to convert that to 2 dimension array. For this I am converting the values of Map to list and then trying to convert to 2 dimensional array.

My code is

```
try {
List list = new ArrayList(layoutMap.values());
int listSize = list.size();
ArrayList[][] layoutList = new ArrayList[listSize][];
for(int i = 0; i < listSize; i++){
    List sublist = (ArrayList) list.get(i);
    int subListSize = sublist.size();
    layoutList[i] = new ArrayList[subListSize];
    for (int j = 0; j < subListSize; j++) {
    layoutList[i][j] =  (ArrayList) sublist.get(j);
    }
} 
} catch (Exception e) {
log.error("@layoutMapDetails () :", e);
}
```

when i do this I am getting class cast exception `com.pojo.layout.LayoutDetails cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList` Is there any way to solve this. Is the conversion of List to 2-dimensional array right..? Here the layoutMap is `Map<Integer, List>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265266/convert-hash-map-to-2d-array

Check this link

Comment: If you used generics, it would be much clearer overall what you're trying to do, because it's _very unclear_ right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final Object[][] result = new Object[map.size()][2];

final Iterator<?> iter = map.entrySet().iterator();

int ii = 0;
while(iter.hasNext()){
    final Map.Entry<?, ?> mapping = (Map.Entry<?, ?>) iter.next();

    result[ii][0] = mapping.getKey();
    result[ii][1] = mapping.getValue();

    ii++;
}
```