# (Java) Populate a 2d array with contents from another 2d array AND a map

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have this map:

```
static Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();

static {
    myMap.put("param1","param11");
    myMap.put("param2","param22");
}
```

and I have this 2d array:

```
Object[][] objArr1 = new Object[][]{
             {"1", 1},
             {"2", 2}
    };
```

I want to "merge" the above into another 2d array:

```
Object[][] objArr3 = new Object[][];
```

So the resulting content of objArr3 is (in no particular order):

```
 {"1", 1, "param1","param11"},
 {"1", 1, "param2","param22"},

 {"2", 2,"param1","param11"},
 {"2", 2,"param2","param22"
```

I understand that I probably need

```
new Object[objArr1 * myMap.size()][4];
```

but can't create a proper nested for loop to do this. I've tried to combine solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617016/how-do-i-copy-a-2-dimensional-array-in-java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265266/convert-hash-map-to-2d-array) but to no avail.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Attempts were made and they're gibberish

Comment: We need to see these attempts to be able to help you.  Please read the link I offered thoroughly to understand what you should do now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.
It iterates over all rows of the array, and all key/value pairs of the map, combining both of them in a new row. And then putting each row in the output-array.

```
static Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();

static {
    map1.put("param1","param11");
    map1.put("param2","param22");
}

static Object[][] array1 = new Object[][]{
            {"1", 1},
            {"2", 2}
};

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    // the new array has precisely N*M rows
    // where N is the number of rows in the input array
    // and M is the number of entries in the map
    Object[][] newArray = new Object[array1.length * map1.size()][4];
    int index = 0;
    for(int row=0;row<array1.length;row++)
    {
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> en : map1.entrySet())
        {
            Object[] newRow = new Object[4];
            newRow[0] = array1[row][0];
            newRow[1] = array1[row][1];
            newRow[2] = en.getKey();
            newRow[3] = en.getValue();
            newArray[index] = newRow;
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

if I then output the array, I get

> 1  1   param1  param11
>   1  1   param2  param22
>   2  2   param1  param11
>   2  2   param2  param22

Comment: thanks. newArray[index] = newRow; was the key part i was missing

Comment: Actually, this doesn't produce exactly the expected content of objArr3 mentioned in question.

Comment: I forgot to index array1 on row. I've changed the code. It's only a slight modification. And I added my output.

Answer (score 0):

I needed an `Object[][]` as a final product for TestNg's `@DataPovider`, but I couldn't get around problems due to arrays being of fixed size. So I do all the manipulations with a list of lists and as a final step convert that to a 2d array:

```
public class main {

static Map<Object, Object> myMap = new HashMap<>();

static {
     myMap.put("1","1");
     myMap.put("2","2");
     myMap.put("3","3");
}


public static void main(String[] args){

    List<List<Object>> list = asList(
                         asList("param1", "param11"),
                         asList("param2", "param22")
                       );

    Object[][] finaList = mergeListWithMap(list, myMap);

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(finaList));

}

private static Object[][] mergeListWithMap(List<List<Object>> list, Map<Object, Object> myMap) {
    List<List<Object>> newList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(List<Object> o : list){

         for(Map.Entry<Object, Object> en : myMap.entrySet()){
                List<Object> nl = new ArrayList<>(o); // copy original containing "param<x>", "param<xx>"
                nl.add(en.getKey());       // append               
                nl.add(en.getValue());     // append
                newList.add(nl);           // add final result to new list to be returned
         }
    }

    // Convert list of lists -> 2d-array
    Object[][] finaList = newList.stream()
            .map(l -> l.stream().toArray(Object[]::new))
            .toArray(Object[][]::new);

    return finaList;
}


private static <T> List<T> asList(T ... items) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (T item : items) {
        list.add(item);
    }
    return list;
}
```

}

Output:

```
 [param1, param11, 1, 1]
 [param1, param11, 2, 2]
 [param1, param11, 3, 3]
 [param2, param22, 1, 1]
 [param2, param22, 2, 2]
 [param2, param22, 3, 3]
```