# I am facing a problem when trying to push Hashtable as dataProvider in TestNg

Tags: testng, dataprovider

```java
package PractiseTestNg;

import java.util.Hashtable;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class DataproviderTest {
    @Test(dataProvider = "getData")
    public void datavalues(Hashtable<String, String> table)
    {
        System.out.print(table.get("Username"));        
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] getData()
    {
        Object[][] data=new Object[2][2];
        Hashtable<String, String> table=new Hashtable<String, String>();
        table.put("Username", "Arghya");
        data[0][0]= table;
        return data;    
    }
}
```

Error I am getting is as follows:

> [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.2.0 [TestNGContentHandler] [WARN] It is strongly recommended to add "> 
>    " at the top of your file, otherwise TestNG may fail or not work as expected.
>   FAILED: datavalues
>   org.testng.internal.reflect.MethodMatcherException: 
>   [public void PractiseTestNg.DataproviderTest.datavalues(java.util.Hashtable)] has no parameters defined but was found to be using a data provider (either explicitly specified or inherited from class level annotation).
>   Data provider mismatch
>   Method: datavalues([Parameter{index=0, type=java.util.Hashtable, declaredAnnotations=[]}])
>   Arguments: [(java.util.Hashtable) {Username=Arghya},null]

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a name to your data provider explicitly, and you can wrap your Hashmap with array this way:

```java
    @DataProvider(name = "getData")
    public Object[][] getData() {
        Hashtable<String, String> table=new Hashtable<>();
        table.put("Username", "Arghya");
        return new Object[][] {{table}};
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @Yevhen Danchenko for your feedback on this, is this the only way to assign?

Comment: @ArghyaMukherjee, no, but the easiest one. You can convert hashmap to an array of objects iteratively, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265266/convert-hash-map-to-2d-array for details